# Mistake in a Runnable jar with two webServices

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jar, axis

I need help with this mistake. I have created a Runnable jar with two webServices, when I execute it with the console I have this mistake. I have add all axis jar at the classpath but I have this. I run this with GlassFish, the plugin of the Eclipse Indigo but I have nothing, please, could you help me with this?, It's very important. Thanks so much

```
C:\Users\cmorales\Desktop>java -jar SincroCloud2.jar
Ejecutando el exe
dentro de ejecutar en Obtener Procesos
dentro de ejecutar en Obtener Procesos  4444
Voy a entrar en los webServices
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: (404)Not Found
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
    {}:return code:  404
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN&quot; &quot;http
://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd&quot;&gt;&lt;html xmlns=&quot;http
://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;GlassFish Server Open
Source Edition 3.1.2 - Error report&lt;/title&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&
quot;&gt;&lt;!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-c
olor:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:whit
e;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-se
rif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Taho
ma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,A
rial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Ari
al,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR
{color : #525D76;}--&gt;&lt;/style&gt; &lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;h1&gt;HTTP S
tatus 404 - &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;hr/&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;type&lt;/b&gt; Status report
&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;message&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;descrip
tion&lt;/b&gt;The requested resource () is not available.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;hr/&gt;&l
t;h3&gt;GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/h
tml&gt;
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:404

(404)Not Found
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.j
 ava:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)

    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrateg
 y.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.procesosProgramados(Wscl
 oudImplSoapBindingStub.java:306)
    at es.uniway.principal.ObtenerProcesos.ejecutar(ObtenerProcesos.java:35)

    at es.uniway.principal.SincronizadorCloud.main(SincronizadorCloud.java:1
 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are trying to access seems not to exist. Check that it is correct.

Comment: which url?, I haven't any url here.

Comment: Of course you have. How else are you trying to address the webservice that you are trying to consume?